# Rotman's Algebraic Topology Theorem 6.35

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am having some difficulties understanding Rotman's proof on Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem.

My question is, why $f(I) \cap  s \subset f(I) \cap (S^n - (s-A)) \cap s \subset f(I) \cap A$? It doesn't seem very obvious to me how the first one is a subset of the second and the second is a subset of the third.

Thanks a lot!

Edit: I got the second part so I removed it (blue highlight). If I understand it correctly the inf and the sup are needed to ensure the directionality of the path (i.e. entering from U/leaving into V).

Here's his proof:
[image]

Comment: As mentioned, $f\colon \mathbf I\to S^n-(s-A)$ with $f(0)=u, f(1)=v$; i.e., $\text{im}(f)=f(\mathbf I)\subseteq S^n-(s-A)$. So, $$f(\mathbf I)\cap \big(S^n-(s-A)\big)=f(\mathbf I)$$$$\implies \bigg(f(\mathbf I)\cap \big(S^n-(s-A)\big)\bigg)\cap s=f(\mathbf I)\cap s.$$ Since, $A\subset s$ an elementary set theory argument says that $$\big(S^n-(s-A)\big)\cap s= A.$$ So, we are done.

Comment: Thank you, that is very clear to me now.

Comment: @User Your comment should be an official answer.